# How to delete lines from TXT or CSV with specific pattern

Tags: linux, bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a txt file formatted as follows:

The aim is to remove the rows which begin with the word "Subtotal Group 1" or "Subtotal Group 2" or "Grand Total" (such strings are always at the beginning of the line), but I need to remove them only if the remaining portion of the line have blank fields (or filled with spaces).

It could be achievable with awk or sed (1 pass), but I'm currently doing with 3 separate steps (one for each text). A more generic syntax would be great. Thanks everybody.

My txt file looks like this:

```
Some Generic Headers at the beginning of the file
=======================================================================
Group 1
=======================================================================
6.00   500 First Line Text                                      1685.52
1.00   502 Second Line Text                                      280.98
       530 Other Line text                                       157.32
_________________________________________________________________________
Subtotal Group 1
Subtotal Group 1
Subtotal Group 1
Subtotal Group 1                                                2123.82
Subtotal Group 1
Subtotal Group 1

========================================================================
GROUP 2
========================================================================

7.00   701 First Line Text                                        53.63
       711 Second Line text                                       97.85
7.00   740 Third Line text                                       157.32
       741 Any Line text                                         157.32
       742 Any Line text                                          18.04
       801 Last Line text                                        128.63
_______________________________________________________________________
Subtotal Group 2
Subtotal Group 2
Subtotal Group 2
Subtotal Group 2
Subtotal Group 2                                                 612.79
Subtotal Group 2
_______________________________________________________________________
Grand total
Grand total
Grand total
Grand total
Grand total
Grand total
Grand total                                                      1511.03
```

The goal output I'm trying to achieve is:

```
Some Generic Headers at the beginning of the file
=======================================================================
Group 1
=======================================================================
6.00   500 First Line Text                                      1685.52
1.00   502 Second Line Text                                      280.98
       530 Other Line text                                       157.32
_______________________________________________________________________
Subtotal Group 1                                                2123.82

=======================================================================
GROUP 2
=======================================================================

7.00   701 First Line Text                                        53.63
       711 Second Line text                                       97.85
7.00   740 Third Line text                                       157.32
       741 Any Line text                                         157.32
       742 Any Line text                                          18.04
       801 Last Line text                                        128.63
_______________________________________________________________________
Subtotal Group 2                                                 612.79
_______________________________________________________________________
Grand total                                                     1511.03
```

Comment: What are `Field1,...` numeric digits? Do they begin with anything other than `Subtotal` or `Grand Total`?

Comment: @David You're right, it's pretty confusing, I'm going to edit the question. Thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton I had a CSV (and you help me a lot during the previous days to format it and convert into a readable formatted txt, with alignement). Now that I achieved an almost printable txt, the last thing to be fixed is to remove redundant unuseful rows. Probably it could have been before, with a more efficient coding, but I'm not that skilled to figure out all the steps in a single script, so I'm proceeding by steps. Thank you Ed!

Comment: PD: If I have to remove the post or reforumulate it in order to avoid an "out of topic", I can do it.

Comment: @EdMorton I completely agree, I just reformulated, sorry for being confusing Ed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a job grep was invented to do:

```
$ grep -Ev '^(Subtotal Group [0-9]+|Grand total)[[:blank:]]*$' file
Some Generic Headers at the beginning of the file
=======================================================================
Group 1
=======================================================================
6.00   500 First Line Text                                      1685.52
1.00   502 Second Line Text                                      280.98
       530 Other Line text                                       157.32
_________________________________________________________________________
Subtotal Group 1                                                2123.82

========================================================================
GROUP 2
========================================================================

7.00   701 First Line Text                                        53.63
       711 Second Line text                                       97.85
7.00   740 Third Line text                                       157.32
       741 Any Line text                                         157.32
       742 Any Line text                                          18.04
       801 Last Line text                                        128.63
_______________________________________________________________________
Subtotal Group 2                                                 612.79
_______________________________________________________________________
Grand total                                                      1511.03
```

You can use the same regexp in `awk` or `sed` if you prefer:

```
awk '!/^(Subtotal Group [0-9]+|Grand total)[[:blank:]]*$/' file
sed -E '/^(Subtotal Group [0-9]+|Grand total)[[:blank:]]*$/d' file
```

Comment: I think you're one of those people who read code as you were reading your native language. Very talented coder, 5 stars!

Comment: I hope not since [my native language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scots_language) is spoken, not written (when written it's done so with phonetic spelling making it highly variable and tough to read!) :-).

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
grep -v -P "^(Subtotal Group \d+|Grand total)[,\s]*$" inputfile > outputfile
```

Edited as per comment.
Second Edit: adapted to new specs

Comment: There is no need to use `cat` and `|`, simply use: `grep -v ",,,$" infile > outfile`

Answer (score 1):

If your `good` lines always end with a *number* and your `Any Text` lines don't, you could use:

```
sed -n '/^.*[0-9]$/p' file
```

Where `-n` will suppress printing of *pattern space*, and you will only output lines ending with `[0-9]`. Given your example file, the output is:

```
Subtotal                                         2123.82
Total                                             625.80
Any Word                                         9999.99
```

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't quite clear if the goal is to keep the total/subtotal lines, or if they should be removed.

Also, it is not clear if the "#*" comments are an actual part of the input file, or they're merely descriptive.

Fortunately, both of these are minor details. This is fairly simple to do with `perl`:

```
$ perl -n -e 'print if /^(Subtotal|Grand Total),(,| |#.*)*/' inputfile
Subtotal,,,                     #This is unuseful --> To be removed
Subtotal,,,                     #This is unuseful --> To be removed
Subtotal,,,125.40               #This is a good line
Subtotal,,,                     #This is unuseful --> To be removed
Grand Total,,,                  #This is unuseful --> To be removed
Grand Total,,,125.40            #This is a good line
```

This assumes you want to keep the total and the subtotal lines, and remove all other lines.

To do it the other way around, to remove the total/subtotal lines, and keep the others, replace the `if` keyword with `unless`.

And if the comments aren't actually in the input file itself, the pattern only needs to be tweaked slightly:

```
perl -n -e 'print if /^(Subtotal|Grand Total),(,| )*/' inputfile
```

This also ignores any extra whitespace. If you want whitespace to be significant, this becomes:

```
perl -n -e 'print if /^(Subtotal|Grand Total),(,)*/' inputfile
```

Like I said, even though your question is not 100% clear, the unclear parts are just minor details. `perl` will easily handle every possibility.

As shown in the example, `perl` will print the edited `inputfile` on standard output. In order to replace `inputfile` with the edited contents, simply add the `-i` option to the command (before the `-e` option).

Answer (score 0):

And an attempt at an awk solution ...

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/[0-9.-]+/){print $0;next}}}' falzone
Subtotal,,,125.40               
Grand Total,,,125.40            
Any other text,,,9999.99
```

Or, looking at the non-csv version:

```
grep [0-9.-] falzone2 
Subtotal                                         2123.82
Total                                             625.80
Any Word                                         9999.99
```